# Write my own printf() in c without variadic args

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I'm writing my own OS using BCC and I'd like to write a printf from scratch, without the variadic arg macros. Is there any reason I can't do that? I have a good start, but I can't get the first argument after the string.

```
void print_f(char *fmt, ...) {
    char *str = fmt;
    uint16_t  *arg = (uint16_t *)&fmt + 1;
    uint32_t  *long_arg;

    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == '%') {
            switch(*++fmt) {
                case 'c':
                    putchar((uint8_t)*arg);
                    arg++;
                    break;
                default:
                    print_f("Malformed printf");
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            putchar(*fmt);
        }

        fmt++;
    }
    return;
}
```

I think I am suppose to increment the pointer one address space and go from there, but it just returns garbage.

Comment: I don't see why this could work ..
AFAIK, parameters are not always on the stack. They are sometimes on general registers ..
So for me, your `uint16_t  *arg = (uint16_t *)&fmt + 1;` can not work ..

Comment: Which ABI are you coding to? Have you read that ABI's documentation on variadic argument passing?

Comment: See e.g. section 3.5.7 in http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf

Comment: Why do you specifically want the `printf` API? If you are writing some OS you could define some other API, and that could even be without variadic arguments

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you mean the `printf` function? How else would I print without a print function? My `putc()` isn't getting me very far. I suppose I could call it `my_printf()`.

Comment: What's wrong with variadic arg macros ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incrementing the address of the first argument to access subsequent variadic arguments may work on some older architectures, but it will not work in general, and certainly not on on x86-64, assuming that that is your target:

> Some otherwise portable C programs depend on the argument passing scheme,
>   implicitly assuming that all arguments are passed on the stack, and arguments
>   appear in increasing order on the stack. Programs that make these assumptions
>   never have been portable, but they have worked on many implementations. However,
>   they do not work on the AMD64 architecture because some arguments are
>   passed in registers. Portable C programs must use the header file `<stdarg.h>`
>   in order to handle variable argument lists.
>
> [AMD64 ABI](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), **3.5.7 Variable Argument Lists**

If you are interested in reimplementing `<stdarg.h>` yourself on x86-64, there are sufficient details including a `va_arg` algorithm in the above reference.

Comment: I definitely thought it was going to be as easy as pointing to the next arg.

Comment: It's register starved, so quite possibly - I don't have immediate access to the calling convention documentation here so can't say for sure. You can always try calling a variadic function and look at the emitted code or asm.

Comment: Looks like I just did it wrong the first time through. My function works just fine with `va_list`s. Compiled with `bcc  -c -ansi main.c printlib.c` and `ld86 -d s.o main.o printlib.o /usr/lib/bcc/libc.a`

Comment: You're using *that* bcc? Wow, that really is an exercise in nostalgia.

Comment: I'm under the impression it's one of the few 16-bit 8086 C compilers